# What is the parseBase64Binary function in Python?

Tags: java, python-3.x

In Java, I use:

```
String str = “%EF!c&WrDwCCTe<fX$,#8L<YTs?G5d>F])ub.63G=Xn<cdef2R{47JQexxN”;
byte[] result = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str);
for(byte i : result){
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");
}
```

to decode str.

Output:

```
16 87 22 -84 60 2 9 55 -97 95 -62 -40 78 -63 -71 116 91 -101 -21 113 94 119 29 121 -3 -111 -29 -78 80 123 28 77
```

Now I need to decode str with Base64 in python but I don't know which lib and function should I choose.

I've tried base64.b64decode but its result is different from that in Java.

```
str = '%EF!c&WrDwCCTe<fX$,#8L<YTs?G5d>F])ub.63G=Xn<cdef2R{47JQexxN'
result = base64.b64decode(str)
print(result)
for i in range(0, len(decode_secret)):
    print(decode_secret[i], end=" ")
```

Output:

```
b'\x10W\x16\xac<\x02\t7\x9f_\xc2\xd8N\xc1\xb9t[\x9b\xebq'
16 87 22 172 60 2 9 55 159 95 194 216 78 193 185 116 91 155 235 113
```

Comment: `'123'` is not a valid base64 encoded string.

Comment: yep, I‘ve changed. It's just an example.

Comment: So what *is* the result in Java and in python? How do they differ?

Comment: I've edited and print the result.Please help me to solve this problem, thanks!